# Showing and editing .gdb layers on QWC2

Tags: file-geodatabase, react, qwc2

I am developing a react.js based GIS website to use various map tools such as measuring distances and adding layers. One problem I have is I would like to manipulate and display .gdb layers on the said website.

Currently I use QWC2 to do such operations but seems to me that QWC2 doesn't support adding .gdb layers.

I would like to keep using QWC2 so what should I do to be able to open and edit .gdb layers on QWC2.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Complex file-based data sources are not a good fit for a web-based application. Far better to serve them from a REST API in a form easily handled by JavaScript.

Comment: @Vince thank you for your suggestion, while the whole GIS is a bit new and overwhelming for me, I would to keep working on my project. So how should I proceed to handle (convert) gdb files on my backend? I can't seem to find documents about internal structure about dgb format, I would like you to forward me to a direction where I can learn more about converting dgb files to shp or kml files (maybe??).

Comment: "dgb" and "gdb" are not as interchangeable as you make them out to be. File geodatabase format is not published; it has been reverse-engineered, but that doesn't mean you want to port it to JavaScript. There is no need to reinvent this wheel.

Comment: writing dgb was a typo what I am trying to achieve is not the JavaScript port of the .gdb rather converting .gdb files to one of the supported formats in QWC2 (either .klm, .json or .geojson). But since my knowledge is limited in the field I don't even know it is such a plausible thing. If there is a way to convert .gdb files to more workable ones I am interested in such ways.